# Trying to understand why validates_presence_of test fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

I'm just starting to have a play with Rails (using Rspec and Shoulda Matchers) to build a demo blog.

I've literally just started and my first test is failing but I can't understand why.

I think I've set up everything correctly, but when I try to validate that a title is present on my Article model but it returns a failure

```
Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveModel::AllowValueMatcher::AttributeDoesNotExistError:
   The matcher attempted to set :title on the Article to nil, but that
   attribute does not exist.
```

My model looks like this...

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  # attr_accessor :title
  validates_presence_of :title
end
```

and my test...

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Article do
  it { should validate_presence_of :title }
end
```

If I uncomment out the attr_accessor then the test passes but I understand that it's not required with Rails.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `attr_accessor` is not required, as long as your `articles` database table has a `title` column.

You can check that in `db/schema.rb`.

Comment: Perfect thank you @hugh-middleton , I had updated my migrations file but didn't realise about the schema. Wasn't sure where it was reading the attributes from.

Comment: No worries. Yep, as long as you are actually running your migrations, `schema.rb` will be updated automatically.